# MS SQL Не могу изменить кол-во операторов в Task

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть сервер MSSQL 2016 - на нем, один Task.
Этот Task обрабатывается и проблем в этом нету. Хотел добавить кол-во операторов, которые получат письма, в случае не удачи выполнения или удачного выполнение. При попытки открыть Editor вылетает ошибка, что нужно изменить msdb-Базу.

Сама ошибка: For this task, the msdb database must be configured to host database e-mail.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете SSIS? Проблема в SSIS?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky проблема именно в SQL Server Management Studio